# I have trouble finding the url and drivers for my HP network printer

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I want to find the HP printer that shares my wifi router, also another linux machine on the same network

Answer (score 0):

Hp drivers can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui printer-driver-postscript-hp
```

In the application Printers, you can assign a IP for the Printer.

in the HPLIP Toolbox application, you need to proceed with Network/Ethernet/wireless option :

[image]